# Webflux test in error: ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ReactiveWebApplicationContext due to missing ReactiveWebServerFactory bean

Tags: spring-test, spring-webflux, spring-boot-test

I am trying to factor out some mock bean configuration.

Here is the mock configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class PvgCacheMockConfiguration {

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public PvgProjectClient pvgProjectClient() {
        PvgProjectClient mock = Mockito.mock(PvgProjectClient.class);
        when(mock.getAll()).thenReturn(generateMockProjects());
        return mock;
    }

    private ValidationProjects generateMockProjects() {
        ValidationProject validationProject = ValidationProject
                .builder()
                .id("anId")
                .code("aCode")
                .name("aName")
                .projectResponsibleIpn("anIpn")
                .batchForMilestone(MilestoneName.PPC)
                .type(ValidationProjectType.VEHICLE)
                .company(Company.builder().code("aCode").label("aLabel").build())
                .withValidationPlanModule(false)
                .build();

        return ValidationProjects.builder().validationProjects(singletonList(validationProject)).build();
    }
}
```

Here is how I try to import my configuration:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
        properties = {"spring.main.web-application-type=reactive"})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Sql(scripts = {"classpath:reset.sql",
        "classpath:sql/validationSupportNeedRepositoryTest/ValidationSupportNeedEntity.sql"})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {PvgCacheMockConfiguration.class})
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
public class ValidationSupportNeedControllerIntegrationTest {
...
```

Here is the stack trace when I run any test from the above test suite:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:116)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor27.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor26.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:146)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:128)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start reactive web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ReactiveWebApplicationContext due to missing ReactiveWebServerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:76)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:61)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:139)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ReactiveWebApplicationContext due to missing ReactiveWebServerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.getWebServerFactory(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:99)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:73)
    ... 56 more
```

From STDOUT:

```
2018-09-17 14:54:19.759  WARN 12777 --- [    Test worker] onfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start reactive web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ReactiveWebApplicationContext due to missing ReactiveWebServerFactory bean.
```

From STDERR:

```
sept. 17, 2018 2:53:36 PM org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader generateDefaultLocations
INFOS: Could not detect default resource locations for test class [com.renault.digital.pval.prototype.api.rest.controllers.ValidationSupportNeedControllerIntegrationTest]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
sept. 17, 2018 2:53:36 PM org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper getDefaultTestExecutionListenerClassNames
INFOS: Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.security.test.context.support.ReactorContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener]
sept. 17, 2018 2:53:36 PM org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper getTestExecutionListeners
INFOS: Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@43f48770, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@32d9e79d, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@69dc5744, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@11a74db, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@6632bc8f, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@1baa4adb, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@10c7489d, org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener@42a94af2, org.springframework.security.test.context.support.ReactorContextTestExecutionListener@310c50ec, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener@78393884, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener@521004be, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener@5ae62ad4, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener@93e9a54, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener@38f27eef]
```

Comment: FYI, I have tried deleting my gradle cache: to no avail.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: No. I was not able to.

Comment: You actually just need to change `webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT` to `webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.MOCK` in your `@SpringBootTest` annotation.